# Запятая и слова «так, такой» и цитирование

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, прямая-речь, цитаты

«Ещё одна такая победа – и у Англии не будет армии»(,) – так охарактеризовал командир британской дивизии итоги кровопролитного сражения».

Есть ведь правило, которое гласит, что при оформлении цитат после кавычек запятая не ставится перед тире при наличии слов «так, такой...». Я права? Не могу найти подтверждение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, есть такое правило.

[Оформление прямой речи](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154) (Розенталь):

> **Примечания:** 1. После закрывающих кавычек ставится только тире (независимо от того, каким знаком препинания заканчивается прямая речь) в тех случаях, когда в последующих словах автора содержится характеристика прямой речи, ее оценка и т. д. (авторская ремарка обычно начинается словами: *так говорит, так указывает, вот что сказал, вот как описывает* и т. п.):
> *«Ничего не случилось» — **так говорил ум***.

Comment: О!!!!! Спасибо!